# Hosting a website in godaddy that runs a neo4j database in the back-end

Tags: php, neo4j, cross-domain, web-hosting

I have a question about hosting a website that runs a neo4j database in the back-end. Can I host it using website hosting services like godaddy? I have already bought a domain in godaddy and would like to use it with my neo4j database.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j needs to be installed. You aren't able to run it on traditional webhostings.

You need to have a server. On GoDaddy you can use theirs Server services - https://uk.godaddy.com/pro.

Or another option is to use [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com/) (Neo4j as a Service)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And in the case I am using Amazon Web Services, is it possible to connect the GrapheneDB Server to the App server created in the AWS?

Comment: @Japex Yes, it's possible also if you're using AWS you can install Neo4j to EC2 instance by yourself.